# A movie about artificial intelligence gone rogue

Tags: story-identification, movie, artificial-intelligence

I watched a movie  few years ago about a man who was dying. He was attempting to upload his consciousnesses to a computer. And when his wife succeeded, some guys came to destroy him, but she managed to save him. He asked her to connect him to the internet, and he spread to every computer, and used them like RAM. At the end I remember some people were trying to kill him but ended up destroying every computer on the planet with a virus.

Comment: Talk about painting the town red

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is [Trancendence](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2209764/).

Starring Johnny Depp as a scientist who uploads his consciousness into a computer to prevent his death (with the help of his wife). AI Johnny then escapes to the internet and builds his own world with reprogrammed machines etc, which getting exponentially more powerful, drawing opposition from the government etc. It ends with a virus wiping out almost all technology, but hints at a few nanomachine bits of computer Johnny surviving in a puddle under what is supposed to be a faraday cage in his garden.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the movie I couldn't think of the name

Comment: +1, but wow that looks [terrible](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/transcendence_2014).

Comment: @Sparhawk I actually liked the movie.  It played a little fast and loose with what software could run on what hardware and the (putative) capabilities of quantum computing, but it was a good story and didn't really force the viewer to think about the holes in the tech side.

Comment: @Sparhawk I never trust Rotten Tomatoes. IMDB is much more accurate and reliable with ratings in general.

Comment: Perhaps the single most boring movie ever made, and that's saying something.

Comment: @wgrenard IMDB is popular voting on a 1-10 scale... which is basically a count of what fraction of people who choose to vote give it one star (how many people both really hate it, and care enough to vote), which has little to do with how good something is.

Comment: @Yakk That's definitely true. Certainly neither is a definitive scale. I just meant that for whatever reason (maybe the different user base), I personally tend to agree more often with the user ratings on IMDB than I do on Rotten Tomatoes. Take this movie for instance. 37% on RT versus 6.3/10 on IMDB. One of them leads you to believe it's terrible, whereas the other leads you to believe it's an okay movie. I happened to think this one was an okay movie. Maybe a 5/10.

Comment: I will keep this one in mind for our next AI-themed stack movie night

Comment: @wgrenard Odd, I find that RT is more consistent with my tastes and similarly so for my circle of friends. I guess it's dependent on our aesthetics.